# <a href doesn't fire after .Click jquery function call in IE. Works fine with Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

Jquery part:

```
$('#yesdownloadvideo').click(function(){
var expiryTime = parseInt($('#expirytime').val());    
$('#fade, #popuprel').fadeOut()
setCookie("emailpopup","cookie already set",expiryTime);    
});
```

Html part:

```
<div class="yes-btn"><a id="yesdownloadvideo" href="<%=yesbuttonlink%>.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none"><input type="submit" class="yesbtn-src" value="<%=yesText%>" /></a></div>
```

Comment: why are you wrapping submit button within anchor tag?

Comment: That could be due to the triggering of submit button click contained within the anchor and also lack of `preventDefault()` method. You need a better mechanism to handle both the situations.

Comment: Are you saying the default anchor navigation is not happening but you want it to?

Comment: Or maybe they want to redirect after the form submits?

Comment: Yes, i want the default anchor navigation to happen, post the .Click function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preventDefault()` like,

```
$('#yesdownloadvideo').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var expiryTime = parseInt($('#expirytime').val());    
   $('#fade, #popuprel').fadeOut()
   setCookie("emailpopup","cookie already set",expiryTime);    
});
```

Also change your **html** like

```
// Remove your submit button from link
<div class="yes-btn">
     <a id="yesdownloadvideo" href="<%=yesbuttonlink%>.html" target="_blank" 
         style="text-decoration:none"><%=yesText%></a>
</div>
```

**Or** add submit after `link`

```
<div class="yes-btn">
     <a id="yesdownloadvideo" href="<%=yesbuttonlink%>.html" target="_blank" 
         style="text-decoration:none"><%=yesText%></a>
     <input type="submit" class="yesbtn-src" value="<%=yesText%>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an `input` inside an `a`. Browser recovery from that error is inconstant. It looks like the input is trapping the click in IE.

You can have either a link **or** a submit button there, but not both.